# Calling a method from a class array gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, class, static, netbeans-7

I've been searching a lot for this problem and I can't find a solution. I'm trying to build a mini-game and I have a method for creating platforms. I have a class with every platform parameters, and I made a class array so i can have multiple platforms at the same time.

**Problem**: When I try to call the method for constructing the platform by sending the parameters I want, it gives me a `NullPointerException`. The method was working before, but with everything static and so i couldnt have multiple instances of that class, and now I removed the static fields from the platform class and it gives me the `NullPointerException` every time I call the method.

I copied the part of the code that gives me the error, the error goes the following way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game ex = new Game();
        new Thread(ex).start();
    }
```

In Game class:

```
public Load_Stage load = new Load_Stage();
public Game() {
        -other variables initializatin-
        Initialize_Items();
        load.Stage_1(); // <--- problem this way
```

In Load_Stage class:

```
public class Load_Stage {
    public Platforms plat = new Platforms();

    public void Stage_1(){    
        Stage_Builder.Build_Platform(200, 500, 300, plat.platform1);
        Stage_Builder.Build_Platform(100, 200, 100, plat.platform1);
    }

}
```

And inside the Stage_Builder class:

```
public class Stage_Builder {

    public static final int max_platforms = 10;
    public static Platform_1[] p1 = new Platform_1[max_platforms];
    public static boolean[] platform_on = new boolean[max_platforms];    

    public Stage_Builder() {
        for (int c = 0; c < platform_on.length; c++) {
            platform_on[c] = false;
        }
    }
    public static void Build_Platform(int x, int y, int width, ImageIcon[] type) { // BUILDS A PLATFORM

        for (int b = 0; b < max_platforms; b++) {
            if (platform_on[b] == false) { 
                p1[b].Construct(x, y, width, type); // <-- NullPointerException here
                platform_on[b] = true; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks beforehand.

EDIT: Here's the Platform_1 class (sorry for forgetting about it):

```
public class Platform_1 {

    private int platform_begin_width = 30;
    private int platform_middle_width = 20;
    public int blocks_number = 0;
    public ImageIcon[] platform_floors = new ImageIcon[500];
    private int current_width = 0;
    public int [] platform_x = new int [500];
    public int platform_y = 0;
    public int platform_width = 0;

    public void Construct(int x, int y, int width, ImageIcon [] type) {        
        platform_width = width;
        platform_y = y;
        for (int c = 0; current_width <= platform_width; c++) { 
            if (c == 0) {
                platform_x[c] = x;
                platform_floors[c] = type[0];
                current_width += platform_begin_width;
            } else if ((current_width + platform_middle_width) > platform_width) {
                platform_floors[c] = type[2];
                blocks_number = c + 1;
                platform_x[c] = current_width + x;
                current_width += platform_middle_width;
            } else {
                platform_floors[c] = type[1];
                platform_x[c] = current_width + x;
                current_width += platform_middle_width;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

And the Platforms class:

```
public class Platforms {

    public ImageIcon[] platform1 = {new ImageIcon("Resources/Sprites/Stage_Objects/Platform1/begin.png"),
        new ImageIcon("Resources/Sprites/Stage_Objects/Platform1/middle.png"),
        new ImageIcon("Resources/Sprites/Stage_Objects/Platform1/end.png")};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem and solution are both obvious.

```
public static Platform_1[] p1 = new Platform_1[max_platforms];
```

After this line of code executes, p1 is an array of references of type Platform_1 *that are all null*.

Executing this line of code tells you so right away:

```
            p1[b].Construct(x, y, width, type); // <-- NullPointerException here
```

The solution is to intialize the `p1` array to point to non-null instances of `Platform_1`.

Something like this would work:

```
for (int i = 0; < p1.length; ++i) {
    p1[i] = new Platform1();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for forgetting about the p1 array code. I edited the post. I'll be checking on your solution and see if it works, thanks :)

Comment: Alright, how can i initialize p1 to point non-null instances of Platform_1? I know what you mean, I'm just not sure how to implement the solution

Comment: I tried it like your code, but it didnt work. I populated it by doing "public static Platform_1[] p1 = {new Platform_1(), new Platform_1(), new Platform_1()} ...}" and it worked. But that solution is not efficient at all =/

Comment: I don't know what "didn't work" looks like.  It's meant to be an example.  Did you put that loop into a static initialization block?

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry i was doing a 'for' loop in the constructor, i didnt notice your static initialization block. Now it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: your object is static; you have to use a static intializer block.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing where you put things in the `p1` array in the `Stage_Builder` class.

Another possibility (unlikely, but possible if you haven't shown everything) is that something in the `Platform` class, which you didn't show, is not initialized, and is breaking when you call `Construct`.

Also, the following seems problematic

```
public static Platform_1[] p1 = new Platform_1[max_platforms];
public static boolean[] platform_on = new boolean[max_platforms];    

public Stage_Builder() {
   for (int c = 0; c < platform_on.length; c++) {
       platform_on[c] = false;
   }
}
```

it appears you declare static variables `p1` and `platform_on`, but you  only populate `platform_on` in a constructor.   So the first time you create a Stage_Builder instance, you populate one static array with all `false`, and don't put anything in the other static array...

Populate those static variables in a static block

```
// static var declarations

static {
   // populate static arrays here.
}
```

Comment: Sorry for forgetting about the p1 array code. I edited the post. I'll be checking on your solution and see if it works, thanks :)

Comment: where are you populating the `p1` array?

Comment: I'm actually... not populating it, I'll do it now, see if that works. I thought it wasnt the problem because i did something like before and i did it using the same logic... But i guess i'll be using an ArrayList as Kosta suggested, see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: no, as this and other answers have said, the lack of things in the `p1` array is what is causing the problem.  You are trying to reference something in the array, but nothing is in it.

Comment: I populated it by doing "public static Platform_1[] p1 = {new Platform_1(), new Platform_1(), new Platform_1()} ...}" and it worked, but i need a better solution, one that's dynamic in case i wanna change the size of the array, i tried using the for loop for populating along with the static platform_on, but it didn't work that way. Any suggestion?

Comment: i think that's another question

Answer (score 0):

The array you are calling a message on was never filled.

You have

```
public static Platform_1[] p1 = new Platform_1[max_platforms];
```

so `p1` is

```
p1[0] = null
p1[1] = null
 .
 .
 .
p1[max_platforms] = null
```

You try to call

```
p1[b].Construct(x, y, width, type);
```

which is

```
null.Construct(...);
```

You need to initialize that index on the array first.

```
p1[b] = new Platform_1();
p1[b].Construct(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the problem. I'll be working on it now :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your problem is that p1[b] is most likely null, as duffymo pointed out.

Secondly, you are using arrays in a really weird way. What about

a) delete Stage_Builder

b) Instead, have an ArrayList somewhere

c) The equivalent of Build_Platform1() look like this, then:

```
p1.add(new Platform1(x, y, width, type);
```

d) no if on[i], no max_platforms, no for loop to add a platform (the latter is a bad performance problem if you actually have a few hundret platforms)

Comment: Wow, seems like a nice improvement. Thanks, i actually haven't deal with ArrayLists before, but ill do what you suggested. As for the problem, i edited the post with the p1 (Platform_1) class code. As far  as i know, everything is initialized correctly there. Thanks :D